# Unable to connect to the localhost/phpmyadmin database through my django project

Tags: python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect to the localhost/phpmyadmin through xampp server for my django project. When i type

```
python manage.py runserver
```

on my command prompt, i'm getting  error.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'djangoproject'")

There is no password set on my phpmyadmin, it is just by default user 'root' and password [null]

I have written the below code in my manage.py file to connect to the database page.

```
DATABASES = {
'default' : {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'djangoproject',
    'USER': ' root ',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT':''
}
```

}

There is also this in my phpmyadmin page on the top

> A user account allowing any user from localhost to connect is present. This will prevent other users from connecting if the host part of their account allows a connection from any (%) host.

I do not understand what is wrong. I am a beginner in django framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have an access to the database. Use the commands below to set up your database

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mydb`;
CREATE DATABASE `mydb`
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE 'mysql';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'mydb_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password'

WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: not working. neither clear what you wrote, would you please elaborate it further . thanks

Comment: what i am trying to say here is drop your current db and create a new one with all privileges.